# Error: file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: php, sqlite

I used PHP to create a database with a table. I did it in the following way:

```
<?php
$db = new SQLiteDatabase("test.db");
unset($db);
$db = sqlite_open("test.db");
sqlite_query($db,"create table students (names char(255))");
sqlite_close($db);
?>
```

After I execute my PHP file from the command line: "php test.php" I get a new file in my directory which is called "test.db" (this is what I wanted). Than, in the command line, I type "sqlite3 test.db". In this way I enter in the sqlite command line session. Then, withing sqlite3, I type ".tables" (I wanted to check if a new database contains tables which it is supposed to contain). As the result I get:

```
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

So, it does not work. Does anybody know something about this problem? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 46):

This is a version mismatch issue.

To open a database using PHP5 and SQLite we need to use a PDO and *not* the `sqlite_open()` function. An example of how to open or create a database:

```
    /*** connect to SQLite database ***/

    $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:VPN0.sqlite");
    echo "Handle has been created ...... <br><br>";
```

Comment: Yay, this solved my problem. There's also a nice example at http://henryranch.net/software/ease-into-sqlite-3-with-php-and-pdo/

Answer (score 13):

I faced the same problem, use pdo instead of sqlite_open()

[this link](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html) is very helpful and here is my code snippet, works perfectly, hope it helps

```
$dir = 'sqlite:YourPath/DBName.db';
$dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");
$query =  "SELECT * from dummy_table";
foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row)
{
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

this is most likely an version mismatch between the php sqlite version and your standalone sqlite executable.

see this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php - under "user contributed notes", from Andrew Paul Dickey.

for a quick solution you can install and use the sqlite2 standalone executable.

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered this exact same problem and have figured out what is going on. (Yes all the other answers are correct - it is a version mismatch problem.) A am posting this to provide some additional information that may be helpful to others encountering this problem...

### Summary:

The error is due to the fact that the `sqlite3.exe` command line tool (which implements SQLite version 3), cannot read database files created using PHP's procedural interface to SQLite (which implements SQlite version 2).

### Discussion:

I am following a tutorial which describes how to use SQLITE with PHP: [SQLite PHP tutorial](http://zetcode.com/databases/sqlitephptutorial/) (Note that I am running PHP 5.2.14 on Windows XP). As it turns out PHP 5.2 has two (incompatible) ways of interfacing with the SQLite database management system; a procedural API ([SQLite](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php)) and an object oriented API ([SQLite Functions (PDO_SQLITE)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php)). The procedural API uses SQLite version 2 and the OOP API uses SQLite version 3. For Windows PHP platforms, the procedural API is enabled by uncommenting this line in `php.ini`:

`extension=php_sqlite.dll`

While the OOP API is enabled by uncommenting these lines:

`extension=php_pdo.dll`
`extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll`

Note that there is a free Win32 tool that allows administration and manipulation of any version of SQLite databases: [SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/). This tool allows one to convert a version 2 database (created with the procedural API of PHP) into a version 3 database that can be read using the `sqlite3.exe` command line tool.

Answer (score 2):

The question is two years old but now it can be solved this way:

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
            $dbFile = __DIR__ . '/../../../adminer/Dictionary.sqlite';
            $this->open($dbFile);
    }
}

$db = new MyDB();
$db->exec('CREATE TABLE students (names VARCHAR(80))');
echo "done";
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php

Answer (score 0):

Why do you open the db two times ?

Try this code:

```
<?php
$db = sqlite_open( "test.db", 066, $err );
sqlite_query( $db, "CREATE TABLE students (names VARCHAR(80))" );
sqlite_close( $db );
?>
```

Edit: Fin is probably right; maybe you have to check the SQLite version with phpinfo().

Answer (score 0):

There's one more simple way to solve that problem. You can convert sqlite 2 database file to sqlite 3. I did that with SQLiteManager program on Mac OS X.