# WHERE - IS NULL not working in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, ezsql

Here's a strange one:

I can filter on `NOT NULLS` from SQLite, but not `NULLS`:

**This works:**

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE parent_id NOT NULL;
```

**These don't:**

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE parent_id IS NULL; 
SELECT * FROM project WHERE parent_id ISNULL; 
SELECT * FROM project WHERE parent_id NULL;
```

All return:

> There is a problem with the syntax of your query (Query was not
>   executed) ...

**UPDATE**:

I am doing this with PHP- through my code with ezSQl and using the [PHPLiteAdmin](http://www.danedesigns.com/phpliteadmin.php) interface

Using the [PHPLiteAdmin demo](http://www.danedesigns.com/phpliteadmin.php?table=Customers&action=table_sql), this expression works- so now I'm suspecting a version issue with my PHP's SQLite?  Could that be?  Wasn't this expression always valid?

**UPDATE 2**:

When I run the code from PHP using ezSQL, the PHP warning is:

> PHP Warning:  SQL logic error or missing database

Is there a way to get more information out of PHP? This is maddeningly opaque and weird, especially because the same statement in the CLI works fine...

**UPDATE 3**

The only other possible clue I have is that the databases that I create with PHP cannot be read by the CLI, and vice versa.  I get:

> Error: file is encrypted or is not a database

So there's definitly two SQlite flavors butting heads here. ([See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513849/error-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database))  Still, why the invalid statment??

**UPDATE 4**

OK I think I've traced the problem to the culprit, if not the reason- The DB I created with PHP ezSQL is the one where the IS NULL statement fails.  If I create the DB using PHP's SQLite3 class, the statement works fine, and moreover, I can access the DB from the CLI, whereas ezSQL created DB gave the `file is encrypted` error.

So I did a little digging into ezSQL code- Off the bat I see it uses PDO methods, not the newer SQLite3 class.  Maybe that's something- I'm not gonna waste further time on it...

In any case, I've found my solution, which is to steer clear of ezSQL, and just use PHPs SQLite3 class.

Comment: Your first `IS NULL` syntax is correct.  In this case you'll need to give us an idea how you're sending that command to SQLite.  That error message does not look like it's coming from the sqlite3 command line interface.

Comment: Larry- through PHP- using phpliteadmin http://www.danedesigns.com/phpliteadmin.php and in my php code with ezsql

Comment: My guess is that PHPLiteAdmin is misreporting some other problem.  Could be a missing or mislocated database file, or anything else.

Comment: No- I was using the PHPLiteAdmin to check why I was getting the error in my own code.  In PHP the warning is "PHP Warning:  SQL logic error or missing database"- Again, the database, table, and data is there- the exact statement works fine when NOT is included... I know is sounds strange but there it is

Comment: Okay, so it's a bad or missing database file.  Possibilities are (severely) different versions of SQLite or, more likely, you're not directing your SQL library to open the file you think you're opening.

Comment: It would be useful if you would add your solution as an answer and accepted it. Not everyone will read through your question until "UPDATE 4".

Answer (score 47):

`a IS b` and `a IS NOT b` is the general form where `a` and `b` are expressions.

This is generally only seen in `a IS NULL` and `a IS NOT NULL` cases. There are also `ISNULL` and `NOTNULL` (also `NOT NULL`) operators which are short-hands for the previous expressions, respectively (they only take in a single operand).

The SQL understood in SQLite expressions is covered in [SQLite Query Language: Expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

Make sure that (previous) statements have been terminated with a `;` first if using the CLI.

These are all valid to negate a "null match":

```
expr NOT NULL
expr NOTNULL
expr IS NOT NULL
```

These are all valid to "match null":

```
expr ISNULL
expr IS NULL
```

Since all of the above constructs are themselves expressions the negations are also valid (e.g. `NOT (expr NOT NULL)` is equivalent to `expr IS NULL`).

Happy coding.

---

The proof in the pudding:

```
SQLite version 3.7.7.1 2011-06-28 17:39:05
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table x (y int null);
sqlite> select * from x where y isnull;
sqlite> select * from x where y notnull;
sqlite> select * from x where y not null;
sqlite> select * from x where y is null;
sqlite> select * from x where y is not null;
sqlite>
```

Comment: @pst- I appreciate the answer but IS NULL is not working.  My statements are delimited fine, as evidence by the fact that IS NOT NULL expression works.  I know what the docs say, but these are the results I'm getting...

Comment: @pst- If it's any help, I'm running these through PHP ezsql

Comment: @Yarin What version of SQLite? I have updated my answer showing it works as expected (in my version). The one thing that is *very suspicious* is that `x IS NULL` "doesn't work".

Comment: @pst- Im suspicious too (see my edits)- the prob is I know SQLite in PHP is different from the CLI SQLite- Is this accurate? How would I determine the version in that case?

Comment: SQLite version 3.6.12 from the CLI... Mac OSX 10.6

Comment: PHP 5.3.4 (cli) (built: Jan 21 2011 00:08:14)

Comment: From the CLI your tests run fine ... strange

Comment: @Yarin The syntax understood by SQLite (for the given version) will not change (the CLI is just a primitive interaction layer). Perhaps there is something trying to "re-interpret" the query?

Comment: @pst- See my updates- Thanks for sticking with this, really appreciate it.  Wish I could give you more than an upvote, but the actual answer's still elusive.  Thanks for your help--

Comment: Hope you get it solved (and post a solution/reason). My idea of "success" on SO is not getting a down-vote ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The problem could stem from how SQLite handles empty columns. For instance just because a column is empty does not mean it is NULL. Have you tested against ""?

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE parent_id = ""
```

That query might return results.

Comment: +1
parent_id = "" and parent_id <> ""
will always work

Answer (score 7):

In Android SQLite, field IS NULL doesn't work either.

**field = 'null'** does. Give it a try in your environment

Comment: Weird... I've just found that in some cases *where field is null* works.

Comment: In my case column type was INTEGER. Android API15 emulator column_name=0 worked. Android API15 phone column_name ISNULL (and IS NULL) worked. Hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

This works on SQLite in SQLite Manager for Firefox:

```
          select * from foo where not baz is not null
```

The query above returns rows where column [baz] is null.     :-)  Yarin, maybe it will work for you?
(The 'not' before the column name is not a typo).

This query too finds rows where baz is null:

```
         select * from foo where [baz]  is  null
```

Comment: What is the exact datatype (verbatim, as declared in your CREATE TABLE statement) of the column you are trying to test for null?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing perhaps the PK column (?) and the column is being treated as synonym for rowid, then no rows will have a rowid that's null.

Answer (score -2):

try where your_col_name ISNULL
wheres ISNULL contains no space