# IS NULL condition results inverted?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hi I am facing an issue regarding the NULL condition checking in sql query.

Following image is about selecting row for the table session_testset which has column "sync" with NULL Value.

It has one row with NULL value still it is returning 0 record.

[image: Not returning row]

And When I change the condition and check it for "NOT NULL". It is returning record.

[image: returning row]

But It is wrong. Why is it happening?

And this is my table structure
[image]

Comment: Is there *only 1 row*? Or is it only a *particular row* that is affected?

Comment: Those screen shots are indeed incorrect. Try it with the SQLite CLI, perhaps there is an issue with the program used.

Comment: can you post the insert statement you used to create that row, if available?

Comment: If the query `x = 'NULL'` works as expected - which is sounds like it does in the other comments - then the issues are two-fold 1) the value is not really `NULL` (but `'NULL'`) and 2) the program has a bug/mis-feature because it is highlighting `'NULL'` in red.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519621/where-is-null-not-working-in-sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my knowledge if we use the query like `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name IS NULL` returns the column where it has no values, that means unfilled.Your table has a value `NULL`.Check your code without placing NULL value in the column.

Comment: Try this query, SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sync = 'NULL'

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sync = '' I try this and worked

Comment: but i think it is not proper

Answer (score 2):

I think Anaz has given you exactly what you need.
Having no value in a column is not the same as having a value 'NULL' in it when
you are trying to use IS NULL and IS NOT NULL.

I just tried a test query on a sample DB and these queries work just fine:

```
1. SELECT * FROM sample_db WHERE name IS NULL;  //returns row where name  
column has no value
2. SELECT * FROM sample_db WHERE name IS NOT NULL;  //returns row where name  
column has values
```

Comment: As far as the syntax forms allowed, [see my reply here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519621/where-is-null-not-working-in-sqlite/7519682#7519682)

Comment: Seriously, the "NULL value" is different from the "no value NULL"? This is news to me!

Comment: hey guys i tried SELECT * FROM session_testset WHERE sync = ''.. from what @Anaz is saying and it is worked :)

Comment: @BaZinga Interesting. File it as a bug with the program please.

Comment: @ErikE I think the poster was trying to say `'NULL'` is different than `NULL`. But it was lost to me as well.

Comment: Oh that is different @pst!

Comment: The query that I am using now is working but i think it is not proper way to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from session_testset where  sync is null or sync = '';
```

or

```
select * from session_testset where ifnull(sync , '') = '';
```

or

```
select * from session_testset where coalesce(sync , '') = '';
```

or

```
select * from session_testset where ifnull(length(sync ), 0) = 0;
```

Comment: Note: `x ISNULL` is [valid syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519621/where-is-null-not-working-in-sqlite/7519682#7519682)

Comment: In sqlite they are synonyms.

Comment: @Nipun Jain Have you seen the structure?

Comment: yes mate i have seen i have edited my answer which provide you diiferent ways use it which fit your requiremnet