# Sqlite Is Null can't work

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_ticket WHERE Updated_Time is null ",null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
int Ticket_No = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Ticket_No"));
}
```

SQL i have tried

`SELECT * FROM tbl_ticket WHERE Updated_Time is null`

`SELECT * FROM tbl_ticket WHERE Updated_Time = ''`

`SELECT * FROM tbl_ticket WHERE Updated_Time = 'null'`

`SELECT * FROM tbl_ticket WHERE Updated_Time = 'NULL'`

ALL can't work, why?

Comment: How is the column declared in the schema? What happens when you issue the first query: SELECT * FROM tbl_ticket WHERE Updated_Time is null? What did you expect? Also, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519621/where-is-null-not-working-in-sqlite. In addition it is important to understand that ='' has nothing to do in SQL with IS NULL. Take sometime to know about nulls in SQL otherwise you may get wrong results.

Comment: [weird](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/af7e4/6)

Comment: No Idea, how come my sqlite can't work

Comment: Can't reproduce in version 3.8.3.1. Edit your question, and paste the CREATE TABLE statement and a few INSERT statements.  The right syntax is `SELECT * FROM tbl_ticket WHERE Updated_Time is null;`.