# SQLite: Query not responding when key = null

Tags: sqlite

I have the following tables

```
R: 
rid, wid, sid, attend
1    1    3     1
2    1    2     0
3    2    3     1
4    3    1     0
5    2    1     1
6    4    1     1

E: 
eid, wid,sid
1    1    3
2    2    1

W:
wid, title
1    title1
2    title2
3    title3
4    title4
```

I want to retrieve the title of W where the wid is in R but not in E. Naturally, I will use LEFT OUTER JOIN. I wrote the following  query

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  w.title
FROM E LEFT OUTER JOIN  R 
ON R.sid = E.sid  AND R.wid = E.wid  
JOIN W
ON R.wid = W.wid
WHERE R.sid = 1  AND R.attend = 1
```

this will return the titles of wid that exists in both tables R and E: `title2 and title3`. However, I want to retrieve the titles of wid that exists in R but not in E `i.e: title4`. Therefore, when I `LEFT OUTER JOIN R with E`, the columns of E that does not have matching values in R will be filled with `NULL` values -as far as I know-. Though, when I use the clause `WHERE E.sid = NULL` or `ON E.sid = NULL` the query does not retrieve anything what so ever. I tried to retrieve from the table with simple query like 
`SELECT * FROM E where sid = NULL` but it would not retrieve anything although I added a row with sid = null just to test.
so, maybe there is a problem with SQLite supporting null values or maybe it is just something in my query.

I have been searching for a week now. I hope I can find some help here as I usually do.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519621/where-is-null-not-working-in-sqlite if it helps. See also www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/is_null.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between IS NULL and =NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null)

Comment: THANKS @AFract , the first link helped me. I am going to post my answer.. @ Joe thanks to you too

Answer (score 1):

the first link that @AFract provided helped me. I had two problems.

1. I was putting table **E on the left** hand side of the LEFT OUTER JOIN and table **R on the right**, which does not give proper output. I had to **switch their positions**
2. apparently the syntax `E.sid = NULL` does not work for SQLite although it is written in their documentation on the official site. **the correct syntax** that worked for me is `E.sid IS NULL`

so I modified my query as following

```
SELECT  DISTINCT W.title
FROM R  LEFT OUTER JOIN E
ON R.sid = E.sid  AND R.wid = E.wid  JOIN W ON R.wid = W.wid
WHERE R.sid = 1 AND E.sid IS NULL AND R.attend = 1
```