# How to check if a value is not (null) in sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite

I want to know how can I match if any value is not null in sqlite database. I am trying with `column_name IS NOT NULL` but it is not giving me correct result. Actually somewhere it is `NULL` and somewhere it is `(null)` in the table. I think it will check for `NULL` not for `(null)`. How can I get the result which is not `(null)` ?

**Please Have a look on the picture**

[image: See the picture]

**Table definition is**

[image]

Or what is the difference between both null values?

Comment: `IS NOT NULL` *is* the correct syntax. What are you using to display the values? Are you sure the `Name` column doesn't contain the string `(null)` or that it isn't empty?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah I am not passing anything to this column while saving. If I am not passing anything that means it should be `NULL` at least. But the entry is saving as `(null)`. Don't know why. But you know when I am using this condition `Name != (null)` then it is not giving me anything.

Comment: How are you saving the data? Which SQLite version are you using and which environment? [This similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519621/where-is-null-not-working-in-sqlite) shows that there may be quirks from one environment to the other.

Comment: Also, what is your table's definition? Is the column defined as NULL or NOT NULL?

Comment: It seems you have some fields, probably char or varchar, where the literal value is "(null)"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have edited my question. Added screenshot for definition. Actually I did not defined anything explicitly. Whatever is defined that is by default.

Comment: @sqlab Can you have a look over the definition of table. And also it's working fine if I am using `Name != '(null)'` But why is it so? That I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [sqlite datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> Any column can still store any type of data. It is just that some
>   columns, given the choice, will prefer to use one storage class over
>   another. The preferred storage class for a column is called its
>   "affinity".
>
> A column with TEXT affinity stores all data using storage classes
>   NULL, TEXT or BLOB. If numerical data is inserted into a column with
>   TEXT affinity it is converted into text form before being stored.
>
> A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five
>   storage classes. When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the
>   storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in order of
>   preference) if such conversion is lossless and reversible.

So somewhere along the line this columns where written with the literal value **'(null)'**. And this values can e.g. not converted to INTEGER witout loss.

I recommend to update your table(s) with

```
UPDATE yourtable SET name IS NULL WHERE name = '(null)';
UPDATE yourtable SET desc IS NULL WHERE desc = '(null)';
UPDATE ... a.s.o
```

for all relevant tables and columns, so that you get consistent tables.

Answer (score 2):

You'd match a not null column with `IS NOT NULL` keywords.

The `(null)` you see is just how your editor is indicating that the column is devoid of value.

Take this SQLite (WebSQL) SQLFiddle for example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/178db/3

```
create table test (
  field1 int,
  field2 int
);

insert into test (field1) values (1);
insert into test (field1) values (2);

-- below statement will result in no results
select * from test where field2 is not null;

-- below statement will result in 2 records
select * from test where field2 is null;

field1  field2
------  ------
     1  (null)
     2  (null)
```

**Testing on Mac**

Open Terminal in Mac and type the following commands.

```
$> sqlite testfile.sqlite.db
sqlite> select * from testing;
sqlite> insert into testing (field1) values (1);
sqlite> insert into testing (field1) values (2);

-- Notice the results
sqlite> select * from testing;
1|
2|

-- Notice the results when requesting field2 is null
sqlite> select * from testing where field2 is null;
1|
2|

-- Notice the results when requesting field2 is NOT null
sqlite> select * from testing where field2 is not null;
sqlite> .quit
```

Now, go to the directory in which your SQLite file sits

```
$> cd /Users/<you>/Documents
$> sqlite <myfile.db>

-- retrieve your table's CREATE TABLE statement 
-- and add it to your answer
$> .dump ServiceObjects

-- check to see if your NULL values are appearing similar to the example above
-- if feasible, paste a portion of your output in your answer as well
$> select * from ServiceObjects

-- try running queries with WHERE <field-of-interest> IS NOT NULL
-- try running queries with WHERE <field-of-interest> IS NULL
```

Are you getting results similar to the results I see? Please also include your SQLite version in your edited answer. I am using 3.8.10.2.

Comment: Yes that is working in your example perfectly. But don't know why it is not working perfectly in my system. Anyway right now I am comparing like string `Name != '(null)'` that is working for me but not having any result why is it so. May be that is saved is varchar.

Comment: Is your SQLite on Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: On MAC. Does it matter in different OS?

Comment: OS doesn't matter to SQLite. My response matters. I'll add to my answer a method to do testing on Mac.