# read sqlite from php

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to read a simple sqlite database using php. The php code looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "<b>PHP Test</b> <br>";
echo "before loading<br>";
$db="/var/www/test.sqlite";
echo "assigned $db<br>";
try{ 
    echo "in try <br>";
    $database= sqlite_open($db,0666,$error);
    echo "after open $error <br>";
}catch(Exception $e)
{
echo "fail ";
die($error);
}

$query="SELECT Serial FROM TxPlugins";
$result = sqlite_query($database, "SELECT * FROM TxPlugins");
echo "<br>after query  $result <br>";
while($row=sqlite_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "$row <br>";
}
sqlite_close($sqlite_Db);

?>
```

The sqlite3 I can read the file and do the same select. 
I always get the error:

```
 file is encrypted or is not a database
```

what's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: file is encrypted or is not a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513849/error-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database)

Comment: Note that `sqlite3` != `sqlite`.

Comment: Check that test.sqlite is actually a database. There is an sqlite client that will let you connect and run commands against it, if it is a proper database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PDO - http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-sqlite.php

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mydatabase.sqlite');
$query=$this->db->prepare("SELECT Serial FROM TxPlugins");
$query->execute();
while($row = $r->fetchObject()){
/*...*/
}
```