# how to retrieve values from places.sqlite firefox database?

Tags: c, firefox, sqlite

Well, I'm trying get some values from `places.sqlite` database. But when I do

`$ sqlite3 /home/<user>/.mozilla/firefox/xx.default/places.sqlite "SELECT url FROM moz_places"`

I get the following error: `Error: file is encrypted or is not a database` how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, there is a version mismatch between the sqlite3-library used by the "sqlite3" command, and the one firefox is using. On my laptop the command you quoted execute without errors. (Ubuntu 10.10, Firefox 11.0, libsqlite3-0 3.7.2-1ubuntu0.1)

(Ref: [Error: file is encrypted or is not a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513849/error-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database))

Comment: I have the same library version and sqlite3. But I don't works for me. :(

Comment: What version of firefox do you have?

Comment: +1 for the version mismatch: had a similar problem with sqlite 3.6.22 / FF 12, upgraded to 3.7.13, no complains any more

Answer (score 3):

Around Firefox 3.6 the version of SQLite used for these files changed to use 3.7 or greater. And the error you get when you try to use many of the popular SQLite browsers is exactly the one you are seeing.  (Error: file is encrypted or is not a database)

I know your working on a *nix box, but if you have access to a windows box, SQLite Expert Personal version 3.4.31.2253 supports browsing this file for Firefox 15.0.1.

The current version of SQLite Browser (which does have a Linux version) does not use SQLite 3.7 so it does not open Firefox 15.01 places.sqlite, or cookies.sqlite..

Sorry I don't have a Linux box handy to test the SQL browsers available there..

Answer (score 0):

Still sounds like a versioning problem. If your SQLite library is dynamically loaded, you might be picking up the wrong version.  Check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable (I assume you're on a *nix box).